# firing onload and resize together?

Tags: javascript

I have a video element whose position is determined by the width and height of the browser. It's wrapped in the `resize()` function below. Basically, when I resize the browser, the position changes so that the browser focuses on the center of the video.

I'm trying to get this function to run immediately when the page has loaded and when the browser is resized. Both on load and resize works when I run my page locally, but when pushed live, the function won't start on load, but will only fire when I resize..

It's also very inconsistent. Sometimes the function fires on load, and sometimes it doesn't.

```
var resize = function(){
    var videoWidth = (window.innerWidth - video.offsetWidth) / 2;
    var videoHeight = (window.innerHeight - video.offsetHeight) / 2;
    video.style.transform = "translateY(" + videoHeight + "px)";
    video.style.transform = "translateX(" + videoWidth + "px)";
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    resize();
});

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    resize();
});
```

Comment: Just to check, is the function not being called or is the event not being fired?

Comment: hey there! this is a screenshot of my issue. I believe it's the event not being triggered imgur.com/a/myUC8. The first image shows how the page appears when the function doesn't fire on load. But if I resize the browser, it will readjust itself to look like the second image. However, sometimes the function does fire on load -- it's just inconsistent...

Comment: I don't know how big the rest of your code is, but it looks to me like sometimes the load event listener is added after the page has loaded, hence it won't fire, this would also result in the randomness because sometimes it loads fast enough to add the event listener before the page is finished loading. Is the code in a separate JS file? I'd recommend adding this as far up as possible and giving that a go.

Comment: yes it is. I'm not running the script in HTML, but rather on a separate file, and it's already at the top-most part of the document. I can try putting this script in the HTML

Comment: yup, that should fix it.

Comment: lol damnit Lennart I'm at work... I couldn't stop thinking about this problem since last night. I can't make the changes until I'm back home this evening haha... but thank you. I'll post an update later.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you two differenst ways of achieve that without javascript.

**1. First Solution (without the shadow at the edge)**

> HTML

```
<div id="videoWrapper">
  <video ... ></video>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
#videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#videoWrapper video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transfrom: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Your video can change his height or width it will be always centered in your wrapper ! :D

**1. Second Solution (with the shadow at the edge)**

> HTML

```
<div id="videoWrapper">
  <div class="shadowBlock">
  </div>
  <div id="video">
  </div>
  <div class="shadowBlock">
  </div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
#videoWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}

.shadowBlock {
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#video {
  z-index: 4;
  display: flex;
}
```

Here you can see it working well: https://jsfiddle.net/et2xrsj5/

Comment: i'm trying to replicate the same effect as batmanvsuperman.com (inspect the video and the curtains, and you'll see the properties changs as the browser size changes). i have "artificial" curtains on the sides of the video using empty divs that needs to follow the edges of the video as I resize the browser. I mean this is a practice project which is why I'm willing to do more complicated ways for the sake of learning :)

Comment: Simpliest ways are often the best ways ! :D A good programmer keep things simple. I looked at your link and I don't understand what is blocking you from using my technique. Can you provide a screenshot or a schema ?

Comment: haha thank you :D here are some screenshots http://imgur.com/a/myUC8. the first image is how it appears when the function doesn't run as it should. the second image is how it should run. everything centered, with the thin curtains on the edges of the video. it will follow the video as the browser is resized. props if you can guess where the video is from!!

Comment: just extra note. in the first image, the resize function doesn't fire on load, but when I resize the browser, the function will run and adjust everything like in the 2nd image. but I'd like the function to fire as soon as the page loads, without me having to resize the browser to trigger it.. sometimes it does fire on load, but sometimes it also doesn't..

Comment: holy... i haven't learned flexbox yet... ill try to implement this instead

Comment: Flexbox is just fantastic, you should learn how it work: it's not that hard :D